# c# smtpClient.Send() encoding of ampersand produces 2 semi-colons

Tags: c#, view, smtpclient

When sending a text/html email using c# smtpclient.Send() with ampersand (&) in the body, the email arrives with ampersand encoded as &; therefore displayed to the user as &;

I have no idea why or where it's adding that extra semi-colon. I have tried encoding as UTF-8 also. My code is as follows

```
mailMessage.Body = message;
mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(MailFrom);

if (isHtmlMessage == true)
{
    message = String.Format("<span style='font-size: {0}; font-family: {1}'>{2}</span>", emailSettings.fontsize, emailSettings.fontfamily, message);

    var html = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message, Encoding.ASCII, "text/html");
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(html);
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
}

using (smtpClient = new SmtpClient(emailSettings.smtpServerAddress, emailSettings.smtpServerPort))
{
    smtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
    smtpClient.Timeout = 180000; // 3 Minutes
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Any idea's would be greatly appreciated. I'm starting to think the problem lies outside the application.

Comment: can you change the text to use `&amp;` instead of & ?

Comment: You shouldn't need `BodyEncoding` or `Encoding`.  The Property `IsBodyHtml` should encode correctly for you.

Comment: Called HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() on message and it correctly translated the correct encoding for &. Still don't really understand why it would place 2 semi-colons in the place though if you don't htmlencode...